# eclipse hotkey to paste predefined code

Tags: javascript, eclipse, hotkeys

While coding JS in eclipse, I was wondering, if there is a chance to create a hotkey, that simply does a pasting of 
    console.log();

Thank you

Comment: thanks for the hint. i figured i have to up/down vote, which i wasnt allowed to do earlier. hopefully i finally understand the system around here :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's possible to do a hotkey in particular, but you might consider creating a custom template.

You can edit your templates if you go to Window > Preferences > JavaScript > Editor > Templates.

If you give it a name like "clog" and a pattern along the lines of "console.log(${text})", you can use the template by typing "clog" and hitting ctrl + space.

I don't know if it's possible to create a hotkey for a code template, though.  Perhaps if you investigate under Windows > Preferences > General > Keys you'll find something.

Alternatively, if you're a Windows user, you could try AutoHotKeys, if you don't mind having your hotkey implemented by a separate application.

Comment: perfect advice. the template solution is totally sufficient here. :)